# NSString to NSDate for yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+05:30 format

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

My date string that I am getting is 2014-01-08T21:21:22.737+05:30 of this format. How do i confer it to NSDate?

I tried:

```
       NSString *currentDateString = @"2014-01-08T21:21:22.737+05:30";
       [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+05:30"];
       NSDate *currentDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDateString];

       NSLog(@"CurrentDate:%@", currentDate);
```

It returns nil. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you initialized the dateFormatter?Also if initialized the same am getting the output

Comment: @kagmanoj your problem is solved or not? if solved with below answer then accept that answer so others can use it in future Thanks

Comment: (And don't edit your original question and replace the "bad" code with the answer -- if you want the answer in the question append it at the end, so folks can see the original question.)

Answer (score 23):

Use this code it is working fine your `dateFormatter` was wrong   .

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

NSString *currentDateString = @"2014-01-08T21:21:22.737+05:30";
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"];        
NSDate *currentDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDateString];

NSLog(@"CurrentDate:%@", currentDate);
```

Happy coding!!!!!!!!!!.

Comment: That historically hasn't worked (though I suppose it may on newer platforms).  The final `:` is the problem, and one either needs to remove it or use "ZZZZZ".

Comment: i wish i could vote multiple time, this saved my life

Answer (score 14):

Your date format contains a time zone as a literal: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+05:30` the `+05:30` it the time zone definition. You should parse it with `Z`.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSString *currentDateString = @"2014-01-08T21:21:22.737+05:30";
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"];
NSDate *currentDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDateString];

NSLog(@"CurrentDate:%@", currentDate);
```

Comment: The `Z` will only work on iOS 7 on iOS 6 there is a bug with the `:` in the time zone. So if you are targeting iOS 6 remove the `:` before parsing.

Comment: My Answer is working on iOS 6 too.. You can look into that..:)

Comment: Weird that in iOS 7 `Z` works, because to my knowledge `ZZZZ` will return the 3 letter ISO timezone name. But he it works.

Comment: But @rckoenes without changing date format will also works. If you initialize the datefomat in the questioner code??

Comment: @HussainShabbir it might, but then you are ignoring the time zone.

Comment: But the question here is why it is returning the null?? And also after executing the questioner code and your code. You can see both outputs are same. Please follow??  These are the two outputs one is your code output CurrentDate:2014-01-08 15:51:22 +0000 and another one is questioner code output CurrentDate:2014-01-08 15:51:22 +0000 aftre initializing the date formatter

Comment: @HussainShabbir the question was changed after my answer, thus my answer is correct for the first question.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString *p=@"2014-01-08T21:21:22.737+05:30";


NSDateFormatter *dateformat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"];

NSDate *datefor=[dateformat dateFromString:p];

[dateformat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a"];

NSString *dateStr=[dateformat stringFromDate:datefor];


NSDate *datetype=[dateformat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to initialize the `dateFormatter` like this below in your code. Because if do not initialze always you will get the null value:-

```
dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your dateFormat as

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ"];
```

And Yes, Now NSLog is Printing a specific Date.!!!

Enjoy Coding

Comment: If you execute the op code after initializing the dateFormatter you will get the output. Please follow once

Comment: I have already initialised it.. And this solution is working.!!

Comment: What i meant is after initializing the dateformatter the questioner code will also work though.

Comment: No the NSLog will print (null) if you tried the questioner code

Comment: I am getting this when execute the questioner code after initializng the dateFormatter Output- CurrentDate:2014-01-08 15:51:22 +0000