# How to parse datetime in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My input date is in the following format, how can I parse it using Objective C?

```
"created_at":"2015-09-03T12:56:37.922Z"
"created_at":"2015-09-04T07:08:20.349Z"
"created_at":"2015-09-03T09:22:33.058Z"
```

Comment: can not understand your question. Please explain more. Please show what have you done.

Comment: I have tis datetime format in Json server..wanted to know how to convert  it and parse in my APP

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` is made for that.

Comment: you can get this using `NSString *created_at = yourDictionary[@"created_at"]`. and if you want to convert it in date then refer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993049/nsstring-to-nsdate-for-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sss0530-format) and use date format `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`

Comment: Catch my minus. Tons of similar question can be googled. NSDateFormatter will help you to get NSDate object.

Comment: Giving it as NSString alone will not convert the date i guess its not working out

Comment: Thanks all for ur reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
NSString *getDate=@"2015-09-03T12:56:37.922Z";

NSDateFormatter* dateformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];

// convert NSstring to NSDate
NSDate* date = [dateformat dateFromString: getDate];
NSLog(@"date: %@",date);

// convert NSDate to NSString
NSString *newString = [dateformat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"newString: %@", newString);

[dateformat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"];

   // convert NSDate to NSString
NSString *finalString = [dateformat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"final String: %@", finalString);
```

Comment: for example purpose I added here ....

Comment: Yeah Thank u but i want exactly like 2015-09-03 12.56 (AM or PM).Something like this

Comment: ok sure wait I modify my answer

Comment: Thank U Got the exact one what i expected

Comment: if my answer is fine give the upvote for the answer,it  is useful for future

Comment: @Romi -- its ok fine , if you need assistance as me

Comment: Consider fr ex:In json Array ...Object for key :Message.....Inside that message i have html content fr image ...is it possible to fetch that?Hope u understand

Comment: @Romi - today morning i answered your question using Regex concept , any problem in that\

Comment: Yeah tht is working only if i give img src ..bt nt the json link.

Comment: can you show some examples

Comment: [http://gratitudes.spritle.com/gratitudes.json]  gve tis link in and c the values in json editor ...gve a try

Comment: @Romi -- the page does not load,

Comment: ya I saw the emoji images

Comment: When u give tis link u ll get Json script copy that to json editor and look for message column: in that u ll find that html content for emoji...[thanks for ur help]

Answer (score 0):

your date = "2015-09-03T12:56:37.922Z"

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"
var parsedDateString = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

Comment: this is is swift. You have ObjC below, courtesy of Mr Anbu.Karthik

Comment: why given the negative vote , if someone want to work on swift it is hopeful

Answer (score 0):

Use the date formatter to convert string into NSDate object. And use single quotes for custom text in your formatter.

```
NSString *dateString = @"2015-09-03T12:56:37.922Z";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

You can use another formatter to get the date in the desired format by using

```
NSDateFormatter *anotherDateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[anotherDateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd";
[anotherDateFormatter stringFromDate: myDate];
```